# Vuetify expandable table expanding all rows with the same name

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In the basic code pen for the expandable tables in Vuetify I noticed that when the names of two entries in the table are the same, clicking on row to expand also expands the other row with the same name entries. Is there a way to avoid this?

Here is the problem recreated: https://codepen.io/entropy283/pen/eYJdmLp?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdata-tables%2F
`(clicking on the first row expands the second row as well)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `name` is the item-key on the datatable. Use a different `item-key`...

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :single-expand="singleExpand"
  :expanded.sync="expanded"
  item-key="id"
  show-expand
  class="elevation-1"
>
...
</v-data-table>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/VJn8sEMr45